# Is there a way to trigger the account.updated AFTER the user clicks on "Agree and Submit" at the end of the onboarding process?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm working on automating processes using webhooks between Stripe and Airtable. My goal is to update information in my Airtable database once a user completes the onboarding process (Express Account type). I've configured a webhook in Stripe, listening for the account.updated event. However, the trigger fires just before the user clicks on "Agree and Submit." I want it to activate after the user completes the entire process, specifically after reviewing the information. I've observed that the account.updated trigger is activated when the user enters their bank information and proceeds to the next screen (the review screen).

The issue arises when the user doesn't click on "Agree and Submit." In this case, the account status in Stripe remains "Restricted," even though, in my database, the user has completed the onboarding process.

Is there a method to trigger a webhook when the Stripe account status transitions from "Restricted" to "Enabled"?

account.application.authorized seems to not exist anymore.

Thanks for the help in advance,
LF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't control the firing timing of a webhook event, however, you can distinguish them by looking at theirs [previous_attributes](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/object#event_object-data-previous_attributes). There if you find the Account status was `restricted`, and the current Account status was `enabled`, then it's the event you are looking for.